# transition_reveal() en R - me cambia el fondo y no se porque

Tags: r, rstudio

realice un grafico dinámico, pero cuando lo ejecuto, me hace una modificación del fondo (verde)
y queda feo cuando lo ejecuto.
les comparto el codigo por si alguno encuentra un error.
muchas gracias!

```
setwd("~/R/Scripts - todos/Dolar")
dolardia <- read_xlsx ("com3500.xlsx", sheet = "Hoja1")
str(dolardia$FECHA)
dolardia$FECHA2 <- ymd(dolardia$FECHA)

str(dolardia$FECHA2)

library(timetk)

##color = dolar

dolardia %>% 
  group_by(FECHA2) %>%
  summarize(dolar = mean(VALOR)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes( x = FECHA2,
              y = dolar,
              label = "dolar",
              color = dolar
              )) +  
    geom_line(size = 2) +
    geom_text(color = "black",size = 3)+
    geom_point(size = 5) +
    labs(title = "Crecimiento del Dolar en Argentina en {frame_along}", 
         x = "Fecha",
         y = "Valor del DLS")+
  ##theme_minimal()+

transition_reveal(FECHA2)
```

Comment: Hola @Dieguexs podrías poner mostrar parte de la base y agregar los paquetes que estas utilizando para poder replicar el ejercicio.

Comment: Hola @Rafael Díaz !! ya pude resolverlo... utilicé gganimate()